# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0, why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I don't really know where this problem is coming from, been trying to fix it for while now. when i perform a gradle sync i keep getting this error.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0.

And i don't even know why i'm receiving an androidx error, I didn't even migrate to androidx. is this normal?

I've performed different fixes i found online, including updating all my dependencies to the latest version. Below i've posted both my app and project gradle files

My Project gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
//        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bahdape.archangels"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2'
    implementation'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //compile 'com.github.jgabrielfreitas:BlurImageView:1.0.1'

    // Stated Fragment
    compile 'com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary:stated-fragment-support-v4:0.10.0'

    // Flutterwave implementation
    implementation 'com.github.Flutterwave:rave-android:1.0.40'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your firebase-ui has moved to androidx.you can exclude the dependencies in your gradle。
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But i do not understand. if you mean i should remove the implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.0.2', it would affect the codes i've written. can you explain it better to me. Thanks

Comment: May be you should reduce the dependencies's version or your project migrate to androidX.@henrymaykhid

Comment: oh...Thanks. it actually worked. i reduced firebaseui dependency version from 6.0.2 to 5.1.0. version 5.1.0 was the last version released before the entire firebaseUI code base was moved to androidx, so using version 6.0.2  was the reason i kept getting the error when trying to sync. Thanks a lot.